# How can I add example code to a private method's documentation?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When documenting module internal functions, I'd like to put some example code in it:

````rust
// in private module foo

/// This functions does something etc.
/// Example:
/// ```
/// use mylib::foo::my_func;
/// assert_eq!(my_func(2), 3);
/// ```
fn my_func(x: i32) -> i32 {
    3
}
````

Running `cargo test` does not work because `foo` is private (and should be) so I get a lot of failing tests.

I read about putting `ignore` tags on the code snippet, however this does not seem to be a good solution, as I'd prefer having the code checked.

What is the proper way to handle such a situation?

Comment: Probably unit tests: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/unit_testing.html  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+rust+unit+test

Comment: I know how to test them, but I'd like to have example code anyway

Comment: Sorry, not possible :/ (at least as far as I know)

Comment: Maybe declaring your function as `pub(crate)`?

Comment: @rodrigo no it's not possible, because tests are running with the crate as an external crate

Comment: A good compromise could be to split your crate into two: `my-crate` and `my-crate-internals`. The functions can be public in `my-crate-internals`, but not exported from `my-crate`.

Comment: You can consider filing an issue on Github for this, since this seems like a common problem, but I can't think of a reasonable way of fixing this. Using unit tests as example code for internal functions seems like the most reasonable option to me.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, guess I have to rely on unchecked example code for now. I'll check the github issue tracker, thanks for this one.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: GCC has `-fno-access-control` that mocks public, I guess that the rationale if for this kind of problems. Would that be doable for Rust?